# Property 'token' does not exist on type 'User | PrivateUser' Property 'token' does not exist on type 'User'. (2339) Typescript Generics error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which can accepts two types User or PrivateUser. In case it is PrivateUser I want to update token value to something like below:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  info: string;
}

interface PrivateUser {
  id: string;
  info: string;
  token: string;
}

const obj1: User = { id: '123', info: 'test-1' };
const obj2: PrivateUser = { id: '123', info: 'test-1', token: '' };

const fn = <T extends User | PrivateUser>(obj: T): T => {
  if (obj.token) {
    obj.token = 'test'
  }

  return obj;
};
```

I am getting an error at the below mentioned line when accessing token saying Property 'token' does not exist on type 'User | PrivateUser' Property 'token' does not exist on type 'User'.(2339):

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow the type of `obj` by checking if the `token` property is present:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  info: string;
}

interface PrivateUser {
  id: string;
  info: string;
  token: string;
}

const obj1: User = { id: '123', info: 'test-1' };
const obj2: PrivateUser = { id: '123', info: 'test-1', token: '' };

const fn = <T extends User | PrivateUser>(obj: T): T => {
  if ('token' in obj) {
    obj.token = 'test'
  }

  return obj;
};
```